# Standalone ASP.NET development server

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, debugging

I remember seeing a page on codeproject.com where a developer took one or two .dlls from Visual Studio Web Developer 2008 and created a simple win32 form application for hosting a standalone development server.

It was a small applicaton that allowed you to enter the path, port number, and a "GO" button, and it launched the server standalone, without having Visual Studio installed.

I am looking for that solution but can't seem to find it. I am also aware of the Cassini project, the extended version of it, and a webdev.exe (or something like that) solution, but not the dll + form app.

Thanks in advance.

-- Martin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what happened to the code project article you mentioned. However the framework has the ability to host and run asp.net web applications. Rick Strahl has a nice article on hosting asp.net webpages within a winform app [Using the ASP.Net Runtime](http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/aspnetruntime/aspnetruntime.asp)

There is also an older article on the cassini server on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188791.aspx)

It should be simple enough to do what you want with those articles as a starting off point.